How to prevent the message "File open in another application" when creating excel instance
I was running a PowerShell script perfectly fine earlier, but for some reason this message popped up that's saying the file is open in another application. I have checked task manager and the excel process is not active. How do I prevent this message?
message
# create excel instance
$excel = new-object -comobject excel.application

# show excel instance
$excel.Visible = $true

# maximize excel window
$excel.WindowState = "xlMaximized"

# locate file
$filePath = "https://company-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/personal/user/Documents/a%20-%201st%20Rotation/name.xlsx?d=wffe0f3f574fd4e40810b1dc67d6dd298&csf=1&web=1&e=JDzZT2"

# open excel workbook
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($filePath)

# set excel worksheet
$worksheet = $workbook.ActiveSheet

# get yesterdays date
$yesterdaysDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString("M/d/yyyy")

# unfilter excel worksheet
if ($worksheet.AutoFilterMode) {
    $worksheet.AutoFilterMode = $false
}

# filter excel worksheet
$filter = $worksheet.ListObjects("OfficeForms.Table").Range.AutoFilter(3, $yesterdaysDate)

# define microzones
$zone1 = @()
$zone2 = @()
$zone3 = @()
$zone4 = @()
$zone5 = @()
$zone6 = @()
$zone7 = @()
$superZone = @($zone1; $zone2; $zone3; $zone4; $zone5; $zone6; $zone7)

# get excel values
$values = @()
for ($i = 9; $i -le 15; $i++) {
    foreach ($cell in $worksheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.Columns.Item($i).SpecialCells(12).Cells) {
    $values += $cell.Value2
    }
}

# remove excel values
$values = $values | Where-Object { $_ -match "^\d" }

# identify incomplete microzones
$emptyValues = @()
foreach ($zone in $superZone) {
    if (-not ($values -contains $zone)) {
        $emptyValues += $zone
    }
}

# unfilter excel worksheet
if ($worksheet.AutoFilterMode) {
    $worksheet.AutoFilterMode = $false
}

# close excel workbook
$excel.Workbooks.Close($false)
$object = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workbook) | Out-Null

# close excel instance
$excel.Quit()
$object = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel) | Out-Null

# garbage collection
$garbage = [System.GC]::Collect()
$garbage = [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()

# create outlook instance
$outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application

# create mail item
$mail = $outlook.CreateItem(0)

# Set mail values
$mail.To = "address"
$mail.Subject = "subject"
$mail.Body = "body"

# send mail values
$mail.Send()

# close outlook instance
$outlook.Quit()

I am passing an excel web URL as the file path that's saved to OneDrive because its autosaving MS forms submissions. I have tried closing the workbook, quitting the instance, releasing the com object, and collecting the garbage. I am expecting the file to close so I can reopen when I rerun the script, but the message still pops up and it's preventing an email from being sent.

The issue you are experiencing may be due to the file being locked or held open by a process that isn't showing up in Task Manager, or it could be related to how the PowerShell script interacts with the Excel COM objects. Here are a few steps you can take to ensure the file isn't locked and to properly release the COM objects:

Ensure Proper Disposal of COM Objects: Make sure that you are releasing all COM objects correctly in your script to prevent any locks on the file.

Close Excel Workbook Properly: When closing the workbook, ensure that it is being closed properly and that the Excel application instance is being quit properly.

Check for Background Processes: Sometimes, there may be background processes that are holding onto the file. Use a tool like Process Explorer to check for any lingering processes that might be holding onto the file.


Here's an updated version of your script with some additional steps to ensure COM objects are properly released:
# create excel instance
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

# show excel instance
$excel.Visible = $true

# maximize excel window
$excel.WindowState = "xlMaximized"

# locate file
$filePath = "https://company-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/personal/user/Documents/a%20-%201st%20Rotation/name.xlsx?d=wffe0f3f574fd4e40810b1dc67d6dd298&csf=1&web=1&e=JDzZT2"

# open excel workbook
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($filePath)

# set excel worksheet
$worksheet = $workbook.ActiveSheet

# get yesterdays date
$yesterdaysDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString("M/d/yyyy")

# unfilter excel worksheet
if ($worksheet.AutoFilterMode) {
    $worksheet.AutoFilterMode = $false
}

# filter excel worksheet
$filter = $worksheet.ListObjects("OfficeForms.Table").Range.AutoFilter(3, $yesterdaysDate)

# define microzones
$zone1 = @()
$zone2 = @()
$zone3 = @()
$zone4 = @()
$zone5 = @()
$zone6 = @()
$zone7 = @()
$superZone = @($zone1; $zone2; $zone3; $zone4; $zone5; $zone6; $zone7)

# get excel values
$values = @()
for ($i = 9; $i -le 15; $i++) {
    foreach ($cell in $worksheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.Columns.Item($i).SpecialCells(12).Cells) {
    $values += $cell.Value2
    }
}

# remove excel values
$values = $values | Where-Object { $_ -match "^\d" }

# identify incomplete microzones
$emptyValues = @()
foreach ($zone in $superZone) {
    if (-not ($values -contains $zone)) {
        $emptyValues += $zone
    }
}

# unfilter excel worksheet
if ($worksheet.AutoFilterMode) {
    $worksheet.AutoFilterMode = $false
}

# close excel workbook without saving
$workbook.Close($false)
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workbook) | Out-Null

# close excel instance
$excel.Quit()
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel) | Out-Null

# garbage collection
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()

# create outlook instance
$outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application

# create mail item
$mail = $outlook.CreateItem(0)

# Set mail values
$mail.To = "address"
$mail.Subject = "subject"
$mail.Body = "body"

# send mail values
$mail.Send()

# close outlook instance
$outlook.Quit()
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($outlook) | Out-Null

# garbage collection
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()

Ensure that:

All COM objects (e.g., $workbook, $excel, $outlook) are being released after use.
You call garbage collection to clean up the objects.
You are not saving the workbook unless necessary ($workbook.Close($false)).

This should help prevent the file from being locked by any residual processes.

AIGC: (1) Compare https://chatgpt.com/share/4df72942-f515-4512-8ef2-9601134b0c6e and https://chatgpt.com/share/e5569c0a-4775-4a53-9595-5a207eb749ca - "Check for Background Excel Processes", "Explicitly Release All COM Objects", "Ensured garbage collection is called after releasing COM objects to ensure all resources are freed" (2) Ordered, Labelled LIst
